# How to validate dd/MM/yyyy Date Format in Kendo?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime, kendo-ui

I am using the following code for asking user for a Start Date and an End Date as a MVC Form

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("InfoEdit", "Info", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Form" }))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Start DateTime</td>
            <td>
                @(Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(model => model.StartDateTime).Name("StartDateTime").Format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt").ParseFormats(new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px;", onkeydown="javascript:return false;" }))
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Expiration DateTime</td>
            <td>
                @(Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(model => model.ExpirationDateTime).Name("ExpirationDateTime").Format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt").ParseFormats(new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px;", onkeydown="javascript:return false;" }))
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

The javascript code is as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function onChange() {
        var StartDateTime = $("#StartDateTime").val().split(" ");
        var date = StartDateTime[0].split("/");
        var time = StartDateTime[1].split(":");
        var dd = date[0];
        var MM = date[1];
        var yyyy = date[2];
        var HH = time[0];
        var min = time[1];
        var tt = StartDateTime[2];
        StartDateTime = new Date(yyyy,MM-1,dd,HH,min);
        var ExpirationDateTime = new Date(StartDateTime.setHours(StartDateTime.getHours() + 1))
        $("#ExpirationDateTime").data("kendoDateTimePicker").value(ExpirationDateTime);    
    }

    $("#StartDateTime").kendoDateTimePicker({
        change: onChange,
        format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt",
        parseFormats: ["dd/MM/yyyy"]
    });
}
```

I have model for the values as below :

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Start Datetime is required.")]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Expiration Datetime is required.")]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public DateTime ExpirationDateTime { get; set; }
```

But when I submit the form, I get the error as below :

```
The value '16/11/2021 11:10 AM' is not valid for StartDateTime.
The value '16/11/2021 12:10 PM' is not valid for ExpirationDateTime.
```

It works for the default format i.e. MM/dd/yyyy but I want it work as dd/MM/yyyy.
I tried using `kendoValidator` but it didn't work for me or maybe I didn't use it correctly.What can I do to pass the dd/MM/yyyy date format?

Also, one thing to note is if the **dd** part of the date is less than or equal to 12, the date passes without any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **en-US** is the default culture, we need to set culture as **en-GB**.
To do this :

```
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1109/js/cultures/kendo.culture.en-GB.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    //set the culture
    kendo.culture("en-GB");
    function onChange() {
        // code goes here
    }
}
```

and modify the Web.Config file by adding

```
<system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB"></globalization>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying formatting in the razor syntax, that might be the reason you are getting error. I have tried below code and that is worked for me. Even that will work in case of edit mode.

Razor Syntax
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.StartDateTime)

JavaScript Syntax

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#StartDateTime").kendoDatePicker({
format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt",
});
});

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Also on the first load of the page the date format isn't what I intend it to show.